# release function is invoked in another process context

Tags: linux, file, kernel, release

I registered a release callback function in the file_operation in my device driver, like:

```
struct file_operations driver_fops =
{
    .open       = drv_open,
    .release    = drv_release,
    .unlocked_ioctl = drv_unlocked_ioctl,
    .mmap       = drv_mmap,
};
```

The release function will be invoked when the process (open the device file) is killed. But the strange thing is that when I try to get the pid of current process in drv_release, sometimes the pid is not belong to the process which opens the file. That means the release() function is invoked in another process context. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because of fork(). If parent process opened your device, then forked and died, and then child closed descriptor - close will be from another process.